# Why selenium server is not running when the internet speed is slow?

Tags: protractor

I am running protractor scripts by running selenium server from the command prompt using `webdriver-manager start` command and running the protractor scripts using `protractor protractor.conf.js --suite Home_Page`

Getting the below error when i am trying to start the server on slow internet connection

Selenium server error message --

[image]

Can any one tell me what is the relation between internet speed and selenium server to run?

Comment: Because it checks if new binaries are available

Comment: @Gunderson thanks for your reply , is there any possible way to stop checking for new binaries and use the binaries which are already downloaded previously